# How to change name of Nested Resource Route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes, resources

My question is about when I change a resource name like this :

```
Route::resource('photos', 'Photos\PhotoController')->parameters(['photo' => 'photo_id']);
```

it works and default "photo" parameter name changes to "photo_id". But when I use nested resource route like this:

```
Route::resource('photos.captions', 'Photos\PhotoController')->parameters(['photo' => 'photo_id', 'caption' => 'caption_id']);
```

"caption" parameter name doesn't change to "caption_id".

Is there any way to change both of them?
thank you :)

Comment: Naming resource route and Naming resource route parameters are two different things, what exactly you want ?

Comment: Please read this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Route::resource('photos.captions', 'Photos\PhotoController')
    ->parameters(['photos' => 'photo_id', 'captions' => 'caption_id']);
```

The resource names and the parameters names have to match:

- resource: `photos`, parameter: `photos`
- resource: `captions`, parameter: `captions`

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters):

> By default, Route::resource will create the route parameters for your
>   resource routes based on the "singularized" version of the resource
>   name. You can easily override this on a per resource basis by using
>   the parameters method. The array passed into the parameters method
>   should be an associative array of resource names and parameter names:

```
Route::resource('users', 'AdminUserController')->parameters([
    'users' => 'admin_user'
]);
```

> The example above generates the following URIs for the resource's show
>   route:

```
/users/{admin_user}
```